# Freezing point of solution of Water, Ethanol and Sugar (aka, Limoncello)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, solutions, phase

I'm looking for a diagram of the freezing point of a water solution depending on its content in sugar and ethanol. More colloquially, I want to know how to balance alcohol and sugar so that my [limoncello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limoncello) doesn't freeze in the freezer. I know that increasing both will eventually work, but that seems unsatisfying.

I've managed to find the appropriate diagram for solutions [sugar-water](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Sucrose-Water-Phase-Equilibrium-Diagram-Mathlouthi-and-Reiser-1995-Sugarcane-juice-at_fig2_311479716) and [sugar-ethanol](http://www.ddbst.com/en/EED/SLE/SLE%20Ethanol%3BWater.php). There are some related research on [emulsions](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.8b01858), but the phase diagram there is done at fixed "high" temperature (7°C or above).

Is it possible to simply extrapolate from the data above ? Also, is there a formula for this ?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5946/does-freezing-a-solution-with-water-always-cause-the-water-to-separate-and-form https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73173/why-doesnt-frozen-sugar-solution-taste-sweet

Comment: That's sort of the point, I want the temperature range at which none of the mixture freezes. I agree that once it starts to freeze, things get a lot more complicated.

Comment: Wikipedia says it has 25-30 % - that's what you could get *after* freeze distillation IIRC, so it probably won't freeze at all.

Comment: What is the target range of your ethanol-sugar content?

Comment: Homemade Limoncello can go from 25% to not-legal-for-sale% alcohol (although it usually stops at 40%), and up to 30% sugar. Arguably, I could find out the data by myself, experimentally. :p